# Minimum and maximum values of a base

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the number 328662 in base 10. Find the minimum and maximum values of b where the base b representation of the given number has four digits. Find these two four digit representations. If the base is greater than 10, use A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, etc. for the necessary digits.

If the four digit number ends with 0, then I can use the fact that b is a multiple of a factor of the given number to find b. What would you do if the four digit number does not end with 0? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n=328662$ has four digits in base $b$, this means that it is between $(1000)_b=b^3$ and $(10000)_b=b^4$. In other words, you are solving this:

$$b^3\le n\lt b^4$$

which is the same as $\sqrt[4]{n}\lt b\le\sqrt[3]{n}$. In our case:

$$23.9434\ldots\lt b\le 69.0107\ldots$$

so, because $b$ is an integer, we have $b\in\{24, 25,\ldots,69\}$.

So, in (smallest) base $24$ we have $n=(NIE6)_{24}$ and in (largest) base $69$ we have $n=(102F)_{69}$

Comment: Thank you for your input. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The number of possible $4$ digit numbers in base $b$ is $b^4$, including $0000$.  So you need $b^4 \geq 328662$, or $b \geq 23.94$.  Meanwhile you need $b$ to be small enough that the number $328662$ manages to make $4$ digits, so you need $b^3 \leq 328662$, which gives $b \leq 69.01$.  There are many representations in between, so presumably they are asking for the base $24$ and base $69$ representations.  Use a division algorithm to find the representations.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I got it now.